# Any way to save an unpublished (e.g. draft) issue?

Tags: github, github-issues

Under various circumstances it may make sense to delay publishing an issue. E.g. if waiting some days/weeks/months for a dependency to update or some other concern.

Is there a way (within the github platform) to save a draft issue?

Note: Gists effectively have this feature through their 'public' / 'secret' attribute (the latter can be used as a proxy for a 'draft') - is there anything similar for github issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way right now. Github does not have a "confidential" or "draft" issue. There was a discussion [here](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/37) and another request [here](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/1648) and they doesn't seem to be solved at the moment.